# How can I remove my vote to close a question?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I recently voted to close a question which [looked like a duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194349/where-did-the-term-redhead-come-from). The OP has edited it to make the difference in what he's asking much clearer, and I agree that my close vote is now no longer applicable.

Is there any way to remove my close vote?

If not, can someone please make one?

Edit: So, the main site has the close reversal, but not this one... so this is now also a feature request for Mitch to be able to remove his close vote here, too.

Comment: This is simply a test of what @tchrist explains. I should be able to reverse this close vote.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on the vote-to-close menu, you should be given the option to retract your close-vote.

Comment: I just voted to close this (meta) question. Unfortunately, it is not on the (meta) close list.

Comment: So far it hasn't shown up for me at least on meta. Maybe meta is different?

Comment: @Mitch Good question!

Comment: Should we experiment on the regular site?

Comment: @Mitch I did that. I already proved it on the main site today right before posting my answer here.

Comment: I just tried it on the given question...it does not show up immediatley on my review list. Will try later.

Comment: I voted to close this question and then retracted my vote and it worked. But I did it right away in quick succession.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I believe you can only retract a close-vote “soon” after casting it. This is to allow for click-errors. I’m sure it’s on MSE.